# How to split a polygon along n given diagonals?

Tags: computational-geometry

Say I have a polygon represented as a list of vertices in CCW order (not a DCEL) and I have a given list of diagonals of that polygon. How can I split the polygon along all of those diagonals into a list of n+1 polygons?

I'm having no trouble splitting the list along *one* diagonal. The problem is quickly determining which of the two remaining polygons my other diagonals belong to. From there, I could split the list of diagonals into two lists, and recursively operate on the two split polygons.

Preferably, I'd like to do this in O(n log(n)) time, as opposed to the obvious algorithm of simply walking around the two split polynomials to determine which diagonals lie in which of the subpolygons.

Comment: you might want to ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: It's definitely not a research-level theoretical question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of what I think is a solution.

1. Let's assume you already made sure the diagonals do not intersect each other and are fully contained inside the polygon.
2. Then (statement 1) you can think the task is fully combinatorial and forget about the real geometric layout details of the polygon and diagonals. Let's think about the task as you are given a regular polygon with vertices [0,1,..,N-1] and you cut it with a set of diagonals [i_k, j_k], 0<=k
3. For any vertices i and j let's call
   `arc_length(i, j) := min(max(i,j) - min(i,j), N - max(i,j) + min(i,j))` -
   the least number of steps from i to j or from j to i along the cycle [0,1,..,N-1].
4. Let's call sortedDiagonals a container (vector>, list>, or alike), of all your diagonals sorted by arc_length(i,j), that is like

   ```
   struct LessPredicate {
     bool operator(pair<int,int> diag1, pair<int,int> diag2) const {
        return arc_length(diag1) < arc_length(diag2);
     }
   };
   ```
5. Now let's cut our regular polygon along the diagonals from sortedDiagonals starting from  'shortest' to 'longest. Imagine a picture of a regular N-gon inscribed into a circle with a few first diagonals from sortedDiagonals drawn. Obviously we see on the picture our regular polygon split into smaller polygons, one of which contains the center of the circle (the case when the diagonal crosses the center may happen only once and at the very last step due to the sorting, so it's easy to sort it out as a special case). (Statement 2) Every time we draw next diagonal from the sortedDiagonals the diagonal belongs to the polygon containing the center.

Now, every time you take next diagonal from sortedDiagonals you know the polygon containing the center (say, you remember the index of the polygon or a pointer to it's structure, etc), so you know the polygon the diagonal belongs to. You cut the polygon with the diagonal into two parts and remember which one of them contains the center to know it on the next step.

If you need proof to statements 1 and 2 here is a sketch.

Statement 1 is true because if the diagonals are fully inside a given polygon and can intersect each other only in their end points then this polygon with all these diagonals and a regular polygon with same number of vertices and diagonals connecting vertices with same indices as in the given polygon are same as graphs in sense that their incidence data is same. So we reduce the task to the case of regular polygon which we need rather to simplify explanation of which polygon we know as containing the next diagonal from our list.

Statement 2. Suppose we cut a regular polygon with someDiagonal not crossing the center. The result is two polygons, one of which does not contain the center - let's call it 'small polygon'. What can we say about arc_length(diag) for any diag fully contained in the 'small polygon'? It can not be greater then arc_length(someDiagonal) and the only case when

```
 arc_length(diag) == arc_length(someDiagonal)
```

is when diag == someDiagonal.

Now suppose we drew in our regular polygon k first diagonals from sortedDiagonals. Each of them cuts it's own 'small polygon' from the whole regular polygon (and probably some of these 'small polygons' contain some other 'small polygons' from other diagonals, it's ok). Now we draw k-1-th diagonal from the sortedDiagonals and notice that due to our sorting all previously drawn diagonals d_i were not greater then the d_(k+1) in sense of arc_length. Hence their 'small polygons' have no inner diagonals of arc_length greater or equal to arc_length(d_(k+1)). Hence the  d_(k+1) can not belong to any 'small polygons' of diagonals preceding it in sortedDiagonals and it can belong only to the polygon containing the center point.

hth